# How to write a shell script which read the variable value from one file and pass to it another shell script

Tags: shell

How to write a shell script which reads the variable value from one file and pass to it another shell script.
Example:

main .ksh

```
read a value from table.txt
if table name daily_load
    execute sqoop1.ksh where sqoop1.sh have a variable of TABLE_NAME 

    (echo sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://localhost <PORT_NUMBER>/<DB> --table TABLE_NAME  --username user -password pass -m 1 2> log1.txt)
```

If you can suggest me in any other way that also most well come.

---

USE CASE : I want to move 100 of table using sqoop where I want to keep all table name and other variable in a separate file. I am thinking depending upon table name I will create a case of variable list.when my main script will get a table name from other file it will call a case option and pass the value in other shell.other will execute the command.

Comment: Please format your code using the code formatting tool (the `{}` toolbar item). Also please include sample data from the input file.

Comment: Try something with `while ... ` and `case ${table_name} in` and show what you tried.